# Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #<NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::CgiRequest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I'm getting the following error on log/mongrel.6001.log

I'm using mongrel_cluster , rails 3 and ruby 1.8.7

I start mongrel_cluster using mongrel_rails cluster::start
But when I try to access the page on browser I get the error bellow

"Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #

```
Mon Oct 11 00:26:04 -0500 2010: Error calling Dispatcher.dispatch #<NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::CgiRequest>
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Can anyone help?

mongrel_cluster.yml

```
--- 
address: 127.0.0.1
log_file: log/mongrel.log
port: "6001"
cwd: /home/maiordes/rails_apps/maiordesconto
environment: development
pid_file: tmp/pids/mongrel.pid
servers: 5
```

Comment: Can you tell us if you found a solution for your answer or dumped mongrel_cluster and moved on to Unicorn, Thin or something else? I am facing the same issue as well. Thanks.

Comment: I am now using ruby 1.9.2 ... this problem is not happening anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, mongrel_cluster does not support Rails 3 yet. Fastest solution is to switch to [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), it supports multiple Rails instances and it's configuration file is very similar to Mongrel's one.